# Increment css top property using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following div :

```
<div id="new" style="position: absolute; z-index: 100; top: 210px; width: 195px..
```

What is the best way to increase the `top` property when an event occurs?

Note that I've tried: `$('#new').css('top')+10` but the problem is that `.css` returns string.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use the [`parseFloat` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to get only the initial numeric part and convert it from a string to a number. For example:

```
var n = $('#new');
n.css('top', (parseFloat(n.css('top')) + 10) + 'px');
```

As a side note, if you want to change multiple elements' positions all at once, that could be:

```
$('.someClass').css('top', function(i, v) {
    return (parseFloat(v) + 10) + 'px';
});
```

But if you are just trying to animate an element over time, take a look at jQuery's [`.animate` method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Answer (score 129):

The simplest way is to use the `+=` operator:

```
$( '#new' ).css( 'top', '+=10px' );
```

Comment: Aside note for new comers. This only works for JQuery greater than 1.6

Comment: Any ideas on how to make this responsive? On screen resize, instead of adding 10px to the amount in the media query, it sticks to the original amount from the larger screen size.

Answer (score 2):

```
var el = $('#new');
el.css('top', (parseInt(el.css('top'), 10) + 10) + 'px');
```

Comment: Yes, that's what the +10 bit is for.

Answer (score 2):

I would say create a variable, increment the variable, and then reset the property using the new value, like this

```
var topProperty = 0;   //You can also populate this variable with the current value.
```

then in your click event

```
{
topProperty += 10;
$('#new').css('top', topProperty + 'px');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var New = $("#new");

function onEvent()
{
   New.css("top", parseFloat(New.css("top")) + 10 + "px");
}
```

by adding the seconds parameter of to css your setting the property.