# Can not use jQuery keycode to change element's CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

I'm following a tutorial on making a character move around the screen using html, css and jquery.
I am not sure why the arrow keys are not making the character move. When I press the left, up, right, or down keys, the only thing that happens is the scroll bar on the left and bottom moves. What's wrong??

```js
$(function() {
  var player = '<div id="player"></div>';
  $("#map").append(player);


  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    //alert(e.keyCode);

    var position = $("#player").position();


    switch (e.keycode) {
      case 37: //left
        $("#player").css('left', position.left - 20 + 'px');
        break;

      case 38: //up
        $("#player").css('top', position.top - 20 + 'px');
        break;

      case 39: //right
        $("#player").css('left', position.left + 20 + 'px');
        break;

      case 40: //down
        $("#player").css('top', position.top + +'px');
        break;

    }
  });

});
```

```css
#player {
  position: absolute;
  background: url("http://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?&id=OIP.M0268adc5eb05ad8612f14346c852f3dbo0&w=121&h=186&c=0&pid=1.9&rs=0&p=0&r=0") no-repeat;
  width: 165px;
  height: 175px;
}
#map {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="maze.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Maze</h1>


  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="output"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this line:
$("#player").css('top', position.top + +'px');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive.

```
//e.keycode is wrong
switch (e.keycode) {
    //blah
}

//e.keyCode is correct
switch (e.keyCode) {
    //blah
}
```

and there is missing operand error too,

```
// Wrong
$("#player").css('top', position.top + +'px');
// Correct
$("#player").css('top', position.top + 20 +'px');
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r6xLj5a0/)**

Comment: Also, there is no reason to use `position.top + 20 + 'px'`; you can use `.css('top': '+=20px');`. See the second answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359184/increment-css-top-property-using-jquery

Comment: Question: I put "alert(position.top)" after the switch statement. Whenever I move the character, it should tell me the position of the character. However, it tells me the top position of the character BEFORE I pressed the arrow key. Do you know what I should do? @AMACB

Comment: Move the `alert(...);` to after the `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Also,

```
#player {
  position: absolute;
  background: url("http://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?&id=OIP.M0268adc5eb05ad8612f14346c852f3dbo0&w=121&h=186&c=0&pid=1.9&rs=0&p=0&r=0"    ) no-repeat;
  width: 165px;
  height: 175px;
}
```

should be

```
#player {
  position: absolute;
  background: url("http://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?&id=OIP.M0268adc5eb05ad8612f14346c852f3dbo0&w=121&h=186&c=0&pid=1.9&rs=0&p=0&r=0"    ) ;
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
  width: 165px;
  height: 175px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `e.keyCode` instead of `e.keycode`.