# Incrementing CSS value by a percent with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to increment a % value of a CSS element with jQuery as is outlined in the answer with 104 upvotes here ([Increment css top property using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359184/increment-css-top-property-using-jquery)).

I've created this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/twLxa3o7/) to play with.  It's supposed to increment the brightness of the image down 10% each time you click the button, but it's not working.  The primary line of code is `$("#image-" + image_id + "").css("-webkit-filter", "brightness(-=10%)");`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you think you could `-=10%` ?

Comment: In your Fiddle you don't call the function; although, as adeneo implies, using `-=10%` seems unlikely to work.

Comment: Referencing the quote from the CSS documentation found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660711/increasing-css-values-with-jquery, this should work.  Changing it to `+=10%` doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle to make it work: https://jsfiddle.net/1q3mtm1e/

The initial brightness is declared in the code, and whenever you click the button the function gets the image ID from the data-image-id attribute on the button. It will then subtract 10% from the initial brightness and apply the new brightness.

```
var brightness = 50;

function darkenImage(imageId, brightness) {
    $("#image-" + imageId + "").css("-webkit-filter", "brightness(" + brightness + "%");
}

$(".button-class-here").on( "click", function() {
    var imageId = $(this).data("image-id");
    brightness -= 10;
    darkenImage(imageId, brightness);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable which stores the value to be set as a `Number`, increment variable by `10`, concatenate `"%"`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var n = 0;

  function darken_image(image_id) {
    $("#image-" + image_id + "")
      .css("-webkit-filter", "brightness(" + (n += 10) + "%)");
    console.log("n:", n)
    return false;
  }
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="darken_image(23)">+</button>
<span id="image-23" style="border: 1px red dashed; display: block; position: relative; clear: both; -webkit-filter: brightness(100%);">
    <img src="https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/29712">
</span>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/twLxa3o7/2/